# How i can sort HTML elements by data-id?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Hello i have a problem with sort on my small project, i want to sort every added "to do list" element with jquery, the problem is that they are not in table so i have no idea how to do this, at the moment i have sorted only data-id but how sort it in html ?

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {
$(function () {


const topic = document.querySelector('.todo input');
const textarea = document.querySelector('.todo textarea');
const button = document.querySelector('.todo button');
const checkboxes = document.querySelectorAll('.checkboxes input');
const toDoLists = document.querySelector('.to-do-lists');





//Geting time in good format with 0 if seconds, minutes or hours are from 1 to 9

    let myDate = new Date();

    setInterval(function () {
        myDate = new Date();
    },1000)

    let myDateString;
    let myTimeString;

    function whatTime() {
        myDate.setDate(myDate.getDate() + 20);
        myDateString = ('0' + myDate.getDate()).slice(-2) + '/' + ('0' + (myDate.getMonth()+1)).slice(-2) + '/' + myDate.getFullYear();
        myTimeString = (myDate.getHours()<10?'0':'') +myDate.getHours()+':'+(myDate.getMinutes()<10?'0':'')+myDate.getMinutes()+':'+(myDate.getSeconds()<10?'0':'') + myDate.getSeconds()
    }


    let classList;
    let id = 1;

    //Function with colors for level of important task

    function changeColor() {
        checkboxes.forEach((value) => {
            if (value.checked === true) {
                if (value.dataset.color === 'red') {
                    classList = 'red-shadow';
                    id = 1;
                }
                if (value.dataset.color === 'yellow') {
                    classList = 'yellow-shadow';
                    id = 2;
                }
                if (value.dataset.color === 'green') {
                    classList = 'green-shadow';
                    id = 3;
                }
            }
        })
    }


    // Add new elements to html every time you add new task.

    let newArr = [];

    function countArray() {
        newArr.push(id)
    }

    button.addEventListener('click',() => {
        if(topic.value.length >= 4 & textarea.value.length >= 5){
            whatTime();
            changeColor();
            const elements = `<div class="list-elem ${classList}" data-id=${id}>
                <div class="to-do-date">
                    <h3>${myDateString + ' ' + myTimeString}</h3>
                </div>
                <i class="fas fa-times" style="display: flex;"></i>
                <div class="to-do-topic">
                    <h1>${topic.value}</h1>
                </div>
                <div class="to-do-text">
                    <p>${textarea.value}</p>
                </div>
            </div>`;
            toDoLists.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', elements);
            topic.value = '';
            textarea.value = '';
            getElement();
        countArray()
        } else {
            alert('Required fields have not been filled out\n' +
                '* Topic min. 4 letters\n' +
                '* Task  min. 5 letters')
        }
    });

    // Sorting elements by : important , lowest and date

    console.log(newArr)

    function importantOption() {
        $('.list-elem').each(function () {
            newArr.sort(function (a,b) {
               return b - a;
            })

        })
        console.log('sortowanie important')
    }

    function lowestOption() {
        console.log('sortowanie lowest')
    }

    function dateOption() {
        console.log('sortowanie date')
    }


    // Remove element on click X

    function getElement() {
            $('.fa-times').on('click', function () {
               $(this).parent().remove()
            })
    }

    // Choose selected option here

    let $select = $('.select select');

    function test() {
        let $select2 = $('.select option:selected');
        $select2.each(function() {
            if ($(this).val() === 'important') {
                importantOption()
            } else if ($(this).val() === 'lowest') {
                lowestOption()
            } else {
                dateOption()
            }
        })
    }

    $select.change(function () {
        test()
    })





})
});
```

So do i need use table here ? or is any way to sort without that?

I already solve that:

```
function importantOption() {
    var items = $('.list-elem');
    items.sort(function(a, b){
        return $(a).data('id') - $(b).data('id');
    });
    items.appendTo('.to-do-lists');
}
```

Answer (score 1):

An easier way to sort elements is using flexbox. Using the [flexbox order](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Flexible_Box_Layout/Ordering_Flex_Items#The_order_property) property, you can automatically have them sorted, without needing to use JavaScript. See the following example to get you started:

```js
const container = document.getElementById('container');
const form = document.getElementById('additem');
const importance = form.querySelector('input[type=number]');
const todo = form.querySelector('input[type=text]');

form.addEventListener('submit', (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    const newItem = document.createElement('div');
    newItem.className = 'item';
    newItem.style.order = importance.value + '';
    newItem.appendChild(document.createTextNode(todo.value));
    container.appendChild(newItem);
    form.reset();
});
```

```css
#container {
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
}

.item {
  background-color: teal;
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;      
}
```

```html
<div id="container"></div>

<form id="additem">
  <label>
    <input type="text">
    Todo
  </label>
  <br />
  <label>
    <input type="number" value="1">
    importance
  </label>
  <br />
  <input type="submit"/>
</form>
```